# Is there a comment character for foreman's .env file?

Tags: foreman

Can you comment out lines in a .env file read by [foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html)?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

FWIW, '#' appears to work as a comment character.

It at least has the effect of removing unwanted environment declarations.  It might be declaring others starting with a #, but... it still works.

EG

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://mgregory:@localhost/mgregory
#DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:secret@localhost:3306/cm_central
```

results in postgres being used by django when started by foreman with this .env file, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 13):

I **THINK** the app will ONLY look for **specific variables** inside `.env`, anything other than the predefined variables *(pre-defined in the app files)* will be **ignored**.

So anything you write there that is not used in your application files you can consider a comment. Similarly if you wanna comment out a variable then basically any change you make to the name will "comment it out"; for example, if you change `DB_HOST` to `#DB_HOST` then the latter will be ignored because the application is looking for 'DB_HOST' not '#DB_HOST'.

Comment: I guess you are confirming here the way that I guessed the answer I posted earlier works :)

Comment: actually, he also claims changing 'DB_HOST' to 'xDB_HOST' or '~DB_HOST' would do the same effect. Nothing special about '#'