# How do you comment in a Node.js .env file

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, comments

Is it possible, is it a good practice, and how, if so, can I add a comment to a .env file in a Heroku Node server?

I'd like to add a comment, something like this ion my `.env`. I'm using a '//', but I'm just guessing. Can anyone help?

```
// Config var data (the combination of all keys and values) cannot exceed 32kb for each app

GITHUB_USERNAME=johndoe123
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=1234567891010
DATABASE_URL=https://bloombergs.ndas.com
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a comment character for foreman's .env file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713508/is-there-a-comment-character-for-foremans-env-file)

Answer (score 2):

```
# Config var data (the combination of all keys and values) cannot exceed 32kb for each app

GITHUB_USERNAME=johndoe123
#GITHUB_USERNAME=johndoe123
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=1234567891010
DATABASE_URL=https://bloombergs.ndas.com
```